# Upload file in Expressjs bodyParser

Tags: json, node.js, express

can I just upload some on file with Expressjs with `bodyParser.json()` middleware? I'm using Expressjs 4.14 and my app.js snipet is like this

```
require('dotenv').config();
require('./app/models/db');

var express          = require('express');
var session          = require('express-session');

var path             = require('path');
var favicon          = require('serve-favicon');
var logger           = require('morgan');
var cookieParser     = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser       = require('body-parser');

var app              = express();


var socket_io    = require("socket.io");
var io           = socket_io();
app.io           = io;

var mainRouteConfig = require('./app/routes/routes')(io);
// var notifRouteConfig = require('./app/routes/notif')(io);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
// app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({ secret: 'super-secret-code'}));



app.use('/', mainRouteConfig);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});


// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error   = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});



// io.on("connection", function(socket){
//     console.log( "A user connected" );
// });


module.exports = app;
```

I think the problem is in `app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` when want upload some file using multipart/form-data

Comment: [_"This does not handle multipart bodies"_](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#body-parser).

Comment: Okay, my bad. Just try another way

Answer (score 1):

BodyParser is mainly used for urlencoded enctype.

For multipart I use Formidable and express-formidable.

```
npm install formidable express-formidable --save
```

Take a look at docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable)

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, I will try this one